# What is the difference between content type eg: "audio/vnd.wave" / "audio/wav"

Tags: mime-types, file-type

There are a lot of content types like:

```
1. "audio/vnd.wave" / "audio/wav" / "audio/x-wav" 
2. "video/avi" / "video/x-avi"
3. "audio/amr" / "audio/nb-amr"
```

Is there any specific difference between these or are these interchangeable ? And a decoder for one can decode another ?

Comment: Did you ever happen to find answer?

Comment: From what I could gather `x` was prefixed when the ContentType wasn't really accepted.. and RFC was still under consideration. 
"audio/vnd.wave" / "audio/wav" / "audio/x-wav"   ==> official is "audio/vnd.wave"

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2361



"video/avi" / "video/x-avi"   ==> prefix `x-` is a legacy type from un updated libraries which dont refer to latest accepted types.


"audio/amr" / "audio/nb-amr"  By default AMR is NB (narrow band) and there is another type `audio/amr-wb`

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4867

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Any insight on this superuser.com question sort of related that I asked recently?  https://superuser.com/questions/1704586/need-help-converting-a-wav-riff-wavefmt-to-mp3

Comment: not really sure ? would this help ? https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/TwoCC 
Or maybe Customer Support with HP ?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I may just contact HP.  Great idea!  Thanks again!